# Can I detect failure on mshtml.IHTMLElement.click() call?

Tags: c#, click, webbrowser-control, mshtml

Can I determine if the [`click`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752277(v=vs.85).aspx) call was successfully? I'm debuggin an application that click on button (see below code) sometimes it seems fail to do so, I'd liek to determine whatever the click was successfully.

```
HtmlElement button = ...;
IHTMLElement nativeElement = button.DomElement as IHTMLElement;
nativeElement.click();
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by successful? Without knowing what you mean, I would just tell you to wrap it in a try-catch ;)

Comment: Whatever the button was clicked or not, because sometimes (I'm debuggine the application) it seems it wasn't. It didn't raise an exception in that case (the button was found, just the event that seems wasn't fired).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding an event handler for the click event for that particular HTMLElement? You could do something along these lines :

```
    bool shouldfire = false;
    bool didFire = false;
    private void yourMethod()
    { 
        HtmlElement button = ...; //however you are getting this element
        button.Click +=button_Click;
        IHTMLElement nativeElement = button.DomElement as IHTMLElement;
        nativeElement.click();
        shouldfire = true;
    } 
    private void button_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        didFire = true;
    }
    private void yourOtherMethod()
    {
        if (shouldfire != didFire)
        { 
            //do something
        }

    }
```